# Yii-booster TbButtonColumn not rendering icon

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using Yii-Booster and rendering TbGridView and TbButtonColumn within that to render buttons on the far right.

When I render this table, all is well except that the icon for the view button isn't visible (none of the others are either, but I'm not expecting them to be).

I've tried comparing my page to the example here- http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/components.html#tables , but I can't spot what actually brings up the icon image so as to spot what's missing on my page to show the button.

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem? I'm not sure where to begin debugging this. Here's the code that renders this widget for starters-

```
    // $gridColumns
    $gridColumns = array(
        array('name'=>'nick_name', 'header'=>'Interests Sets'),
        array(
            'htmlOptions' => array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("friend/filter", array("friend_id"=>$data->id))',
            'updateButtonUrl'=>null,
            'deleteButtonUrl'=>null,
        )
    );

    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'type'=>'striped',
        'dataProvider'=>$gridDataProvider,
        'template'=>"{items}",
        'columns'=>$gridColumns,
    ));
```

Comment: Is anything being displayed in place of the icon?

Comment: No, but the HTML is being rendered as per the example.

Comment: Are any of the icons being displayed in, say, a button/label? If no, try emptying your **path-to-site-root/assets** folder.

Comment: How do you mean "button/label"? Nothing is being rendered on screen. I've tried clearing the assets folder for good measure, but I still get the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example that I get working:

```
array(
          'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
          'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
          'template'=>'{delete}', //Only shows Delete button
          'buttons'=>array(            
            'delete' => array(
              'label'=>'Terminar sesión',
            ),
          ),
          'deleteConfirmation'=>'Está seguro que desea terminar la sesión seleccionada?',
          'deleteButtonUrl'=>'$this->grid->owner->createUrl("productSession/delete", $data->primaryKey)'
        ),
```

To debug your problem, just look at the HTML generated. It will have a path to the image, copy that path and paste it in your browser, if you can't access the image, then there is the problem, see if your paths are well configured and have read permissions.

Edit:

Actually the icon is added in the CSS, not in HTML:

```
<td style="width: 50px">
<a class="delete" href="/smartworkspace/index.php/productSession/delete/username/admin/product/docusearch" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Terminar sesión">
<i class="icon-trash"></i>
</a>
</td>
```

To load the YiiB css's, I had to include these in my Layout (Can be the view file also)

```
<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerCoreCss(); ?>
<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerCoreScripts(); ?>
<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerYiiCss(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, Thanks for your response.
The HTML generated does not contain an image,I think that's the problem. I can't get your example to work it shows "Property "TbDataColumn.style" is not defined."

Comment: Strange, because we are not assigning any style, did you copy/paste or changed something? (The style is added to the object as html). Are you using the last version?

Comment: There's a style in the htmlOptions?

Comment: Just use your example, remove the null, and use the template system like I do, and see if that makes it. 'template'=>'{view}',

Comment: Hmm I updated my answer. Its not an image in the html, its an <i> element. The image is loaded in the assets folder (so it doesn't have a fixed URL).

Comment: My HTML shows similar output- <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>

I must not have the correct CSS loaded. What is the location of the syle sheet that picks up the image?

Comment: Bingo! :)

Sorry, I realise this is a newbie error. My first week with YiiBooster.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Jorge, do you know how to render text on the button instead of the icon?

Comment: Try overriding the button: 'template' => '{delete}',
                'buttons'=>array(
                        'delete' => array( ... look the documentation for CButtonColumn::buttons http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail

Comment: Thanks for that. One last question if you don't mind. The widget is binding the delete pop over message to all four of my buttons and I can't work out why. Would you have any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: It appears to be applying the delete popover to any icon with thes button styles applied- 'class'=>'btn btn-small', odd!

Comment: I solved it. I just needed to give the delete button a unique class that the others didn't have.

Comment: I was looking for an example of how to change the tooltip text. Your code example showed me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Here is why it happens:

1. If you check the icon on yiibooster website, you will find that font-awesome.css is used to display the icon, which means the icon is not a image at all.
2. If you check your icon, you will probably not find font-awesome.css which is the reason for icon not showing.

Here is the solution:
You need to register FontAwesomeCss with the following code:(One should not add this line unless it's necessary, and you can add it anywhere e.g. in a _form.php file)

Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerFontAwesomeCss();

Comment: Have you tried adding core YiiBooster scripts as per the end of Jorge's answer?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did add core scripts and the icon shows! But they also rewrite some css. Try to figure it out...

Comment: Hey, the Bootstrap DOES rewrite CSS, thats why I don't like it so much, the way I managed to "resolve" this is by prefixing my classes and overriding the ones that are declared in Bootstrap and I don't like much, appending !important to the property. That's Bootstrap fault, that is like "intrusive". So if you don't like the H1 that gets rendered, use `h1 { font-size: 14px !important; }` in another CSS file that gets loaded in the page.

Comment: +1 I tried Jorge's answer but was not lucky to make it work. This one is easy to follow,short and works! Not to mention the explanation is good and realised that bootstrap is using font-awesome.css. Thanks!